# Unable to find an Xpath of an element using webdriver and xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, xpathnavigator

I need to click on the textbox next to username . Am unable to find the Xpath for this using webdriver...can I get some help?

---

here is the html snippet:

```
<div id="form-1013-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default x-docked-noborder-top x-docked-noborder-right x-docked-noborder-bottom x-docked-noborder-left" style="padding: 0px; height: 108px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 376px;">
<span id="form-1013-outerCt" style="display: table; height: 100%;">
<div id="form-1013-innerCt" class="" style="display:table-cell;height:100%;vertical-align:top;padding:5px 5px 5px 5px">
<table id="textfield-1014" class="x-field x-table-plain x-form-item x-field-default x-anchor-form-item x-form-invalid" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: auto;">
<tbody>
<tr id="textfield-1014-inputRow">
<td id="textfield-1014-labelCell" class="x-field-label-cell" width="205" valign="top" halign="right" style="">
<label id="textfield-1014-labelEl" class="x-form-item-label x-unselectable x-form-item-label-right" unselectable="on" style="width:200px;margin-right:5px;" for="textfield-1014-inputEl">Username:</label>
</td>
<td id="textfield-1014-bodyEl" class="x-form-item-body " role="presentation" colspan="1">
<input id="textfield-1014-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="username" aria-invalid="true">
</td>
<td id="textfield-1014-sideErrorCell" width="17" valign="middle" style="">
<div id="textfield-1014-errorEl" class="x-form-error-msg x-form-invalid-icon" style="" data-errorqtip="<ul class="x-list-plain"><li>This field is required</li></ul>">
<ul class="x-list-plain">
<li>This field is required</li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="textfield-1015" class="x-field x-table-plain x-form-item x-field-default x-anchor-form-item" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: auto;">
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: tried by input id, username, class. But not compounded ( meaning- never added two xpaths)..

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
   List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
   
    System.out.println("Number of elements: "+elements.size());
    for(WebElement ele : elements){
           ele.sendKeys("admin");

Comment: no such element found exception

Comment: and also when I try to view pagesource through this :

Comment: //System.out.println("webpage" + driver.getPageSource());-- I don't see the entire page source being spit out

Comment: First, you didn't use `wait` you created. Second, did you get `noSuchElementException` at `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));`? Then do you have iframes on your page?

Comment: i dont know how to find out if my HTML is having embedded iframes on my page...can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
```

with this one:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));
```

Check this cool cheat sheet for further selections

http://www.simple-talk.com/content/file.ashx?file=4937